# Perl: Combine duplicated keys in Hash of Array

Tags: sql, perl, intellij-idea, hash, key-value

I having issues with this and wondering if someone could provide some help. I'm parsing a .txt file and want to combine duplicated keys and it's values. Essentially, for each identifier I want to store it's height value. Each "sample" has 2 entries (A & B). I have the file stored like this:

```
while(...){
    @data= split ("\t", $line);  
                            
    $curr_identifier= $data[0];
    $markername= $data[1];
    $position1= $data[2];
    $height= $data[4];

    if ($line >0){
         $result[0] = $markername;
         $result[1] = $position1;
         $result[2] = $height;
         $result[3] = $curr_identifier;

         $data{$curr_identifier}= [@result];
     }
}
```

This seems to work fine, but my issue is that when I send this data to below function. It prints the $curr_identifier twice. I only want to populate unique identifiers and check for the presence of it's $height variable.

```
 if (!defined $data{$curr_identifier}[2]){
            $output1= "no height for both markers- failed";
 } else {
    if ($data{$curr_identifier}[2] eq " ") {
        $output1 = $markername;

    } 
 }
 
 print $curr_identifier, $output1 . "\t" . $output1 . "\n";
```

Basically, if sample height is present for both markers (A&B), then output is both markers.

```
'1', 'A', 'B'
```

If height is not present, then output is empty for reported marker.

```
'2', 'A', ' '

'3', ' ', 'B'
```

My current output is printing out like this:

```
1, A
1, B

2, A
2, ' '

3, ' '
3, B'
```

```
_DATA_
Name Marker Position1 Height Time
1   A   A       6246        0.9706
1   B   B       3237        0.9706
2   A                   0
2   B   B       5495        0.9775
3   A   A       11254       0.9694
3   B                       0
```

Comment: `_DATA_` ??? https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html

Comment: Needs a [mcve], not random incomplete snippets of code.

Comment: The first snippet displays how I’m storing the file’s data into the %data hash and the second snippet is a subroutine that I call in the while loop. 

It’s purpose is to only output the hash data.

Comment: `== " "` doesn't make sense; `==` is numeric comparison, for string comparison use `eq`.  and is it really a single space, not an empty string?

Comment: It’s an empty string. It will be empty when the height variable is missing from the data file.

Answer (score 0):

Your desired output can essentially be boiled down to these few lines of perl code:

```
while (<DATA>) {
  ($name,$mark,$pos,$heig,$time) = split /\t/;
  print "'$name','$mark','$pos'\n";
}

__DATA__
... your tab-separated data here ...
```